# How to show google ajax content of the root page ? (no '#!')

Tags: ajax, angularjs, seo

Google says if you want to show the ajax content of your page to google, you need to put #! in your link . then google will replace it with _escaped_fragment_ when it visits the site. then you can show them the preloaded page. but what about the root of the site ? we have a websites made with angularjs which has ajax content in the root page. while the address of the root page of every website is www.****.*** with no '#!', how can we manipulate seo for that page ?

Comment: You need to follow the guidelines published by google. Read them some more. They explain how to add meta tag

Comment: which part exactly ? can you show that part ? @charlietfl

Comment: look for the `<base>` and `<meta>` information

Comment: Do you mean using html5 routing instead of '#!' ?

Comment: It is explained for both approaches...but yes

Comment: Actually, for some reasons I prefer to stick with this method, but I will use your help, thanks.